# Android contacts list

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I'm working on a sort of contacts book for my app, I want to do something like in the picture beneath:

[image]

The contact names will be in a scrollable list, but I want the letetr on the left to follow the names until the next letter shows up. I'm not quite sure how to do this, I thought of having a structure like this in the corresponding xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ListView>
      <ImageView />
      <ListView />
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is this the right way to go about it ?

Comment: As you said, I believe using one listview would be a better choice, but in this case I see a row consisting only of the firstname and lastname of a person, the letter on the left would have to be implemented on it's own. I'll give it some thought, thanks

Comment: ,Please see my answer .I used this already .Happy coding

Comment: @innoSPG I totally forgot to accept your anwser, it helped me resolve my issue. Thanks for the reminder !

Comment: No problem, the most important is that you did. And it helps those who have similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to add an `OnScrollListener` (`listView.setOnScrollListener`) to your listview. Then implements the methods

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
```

and/or

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
```

With the first one, you have a lot of information to use to manage what you want. For example, if you want the letter to correspond to the first element in the list view, You get the first letter of the first element and `draw it`.

Answer (score 2):

@Husayn Hakeem : For your information,Your requiremet is Lollipop's Contacts. Its special type of ListView ([PinnedHeaderListView](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView/blob/master/library/src/za/co/immedia/pinnedheaderlistview/PinnedHeaderListView.java))with pinned section headers for Android.So please check [ListViewVariants](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants) Demo .I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it with a `RecyclerView` you can take a look at this [project](https://github.com/Joseph82/PinnedList-Android). You can customize the left pin either with a simple text or an image.

The idea is to use a `CoordinatorLayout` in which you have the pin. Assigning a behavior to this pin you can get the result you want.